# How to generate a new structure with lodash?

Tags: arrays, object, lodash

I need help to generate new structure with lodash
i have this data:

```
items: [
    { color: 'Green', size: 'Large', style: 'Skinny' },
    { color: 'Blue', size: 'Small', style: 'Tapered' },
    { color: 'Red', size: 'Medium', style: 'Slim' },
    { color: 'Blue', size: 'Large', style: 'Tapered' },
  ];
```

but i need something like that grouped by Style:

```
[
{
  group: 'Skinny',
  items: [
    { color: 'Green', size: 'Large', style: 'Skinny' }
  ]
}
{
  group: 'Tapered',
  items: [
     { color: 'Blue', size: 'Small', style: 'Tapered' },
     { color: 'Blue', size: 'Large', style: 'Tapered' }
  ]
}
{
  group: 'Slim',
  items: [
    { color: 'Red', size: 'Medium', style: 'Slim' }
  ]
}
```

]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) to collect the objects, then [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to the required form:

```js
var items = [
  { color: 'Green', size: 'Large', style: 'Skinny' },
  { color: 'Blue', size: 'Small', style: 'Tapered' },
  { color: 'Red', size: 'Medium', style: 'Slim' },
  { color: 'Blue', size: 'Large', style: 'Tapered' },
];

var result = _(items)
  .groupBy('style')
  .map(function(v, k) {
    return {
      group: k,
      items: v
    };
  })
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @JulioCesarMontenegro - enjoy :)